# Why does a simple std::deque<int> not free all memory on exit?

Tags: c++, linux, valgrind

The following code

```
#include <deque>
int main() {
  std::deque<int> Q;
  return 0;
}
```

produces a non-clean exit as per valgrind:

```
==9942== HEAP SUMMARY:
==9942==     in use at exit: 72,704 bytes in 1 blocks
==9942==   total heap usage: 3 allocs, 2 frees, 73,280 bytes allocated
==9942== 
==9942== LEAK SUMMARY:
==9942==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==9942==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==9942==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==9942==    still reachable: 72,704 bytes in 1 blocks
==9942==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
```

Code compiled with g++ on Linux Mint.

Is this a bug in the standard library?

Is there any way to get a clean exit?

Changing to a "`new`/`delete`" methodology just reports 4 allocs and 3 frees...

Comment: You're probably seeing stuff that was allocated by the runtime.  If `deque` leaked there would be a lot of broken code out there.

Comment: It could be an optimization. The implementer of the standard library knows that the system uses virtual memory, so it speeds up process termination by leaking the memory on purpose. Just a guess, though.

Comment: I somehow doubt an empty deque would take 72 704 bytes of memory. Are you sure the deque is responsible for that allocation?

Comment: Can't reproduce. What do you see without deque?

Comment: "definitely lost: 0 bytes" <-- it's only a "real" memory leak if this one is non-zero.  I think you're fine.

Comment: This is definitely an issue with my particular linux box.  I've tried it on several other computers and valgrind reports completely clean with only 128bytes used (as opposed to >70KB).  I downloaded and compiled gcc v5.4 with minimal options and am still having the same issue.  If I figure it out I'll post back.